# Xamarin.Android show current time

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin and I am trying to do A ToDoListApp. And I want to add a time stamp when a make a new task. I found something in Java but I'm working with c# and I would like to know what is the equivalent to `String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());`

Comment: and how can I show only day/month?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
 String myDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now; // will give the date time for today
```